# Регулярное выражение не ищет знак "\"

Tags: python, строки

Есть строка, допустим:

```
text = '''sdfd 9999998\ 7237465 '''
```

нужно извлечь из него числа 9999998 и 7237465
Между числами может быть либо запятая, либо косая черта "" и после них пробелы.
Просто [\d]+ не подходит, так как паршу номера телефонов, чтобы найти телефоны вида "+7(800)5553535\5563636 и добавлять одинаковое начало номера (+7800). На странице могут быть номера с разными кодами.

Регурарное выражение следующего вида:

```
re.findall(r'[\d]+[,\\][\s]*[\d]+', text)
```

находит все варианты

```
text = '''sdfd 9999998,7237465 '''
text = '''sdfd 9999998, 7237465 '''
text = '''sdfd 9999998\ 7237465 '''
```

кроме (после "\" нет пробела)

```
text = '''sdfd 9999998\7237465 '''
```

Как подправить регулярное выражение, чтобы найти числа во всех 4 случаях?

Comment: тут только кусок того что мне нужно. Паршу номера телефонов, чтобы найти телефоны вида "+7(800)5553535\5563636 и добавлять одинаковое начало номера (+7800). На странице могут быть номера с разными кодами.

Comment: На сайте это работает \d+[\\s,]+\s*\d+
Но при text = '''9999998\7237465'''
 re.findall(r'\d+[\\s,]+[\s]*\d+', text)
не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше регулярное выражение прекрасно работает. Только не забывайте, что python обрабатывает символ косой черты как знак экранирования и в итоге строка приобретает  следующий вид:

```
'sdfd 9999998\7237465' -> 'sdfd 9999998Ǔ7465'
```

Создавайте необработанные строки указывая перед открывающей строкой префикс "r":

```
r'sdfd 9999998\7237465' -> 'sdfd 9999998\\7237465'
```

Где "\\" экранирование экранирования.